# How to send the data written to a file (.csv) to a folder on my desktop (directory)?

Tags: python, file, csv

Essentially the data is temperatures from 4 different states over the course of 12 months, so there is 48 files to be populated into my folder on my desktop directory. But I am not sure how to take the data being pulled from the web and then take the files being saved in my program to be sent to the directory of my desktop. That's what I am confused about, how to take the files being created on in my program and send them to a folder on my desktop.

I am copying the data from the web, cleaning it up, then saving it into a file, then taking that file and wanting to save it to a folder on my desktop.

Here is the code:

```
import urllib


def accessData(Id, Month):
    url = "https://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=" + str(Id) + "&year=2017&month=" + str(Month) + "&graphspan=month&format=1"
    infile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    readLineByLine = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()

    return readLineByLine


f = open('stations.csv', 'r')

for line in f.readlines():
    vals = line.split(',')

    for j in range(1,13): # accessing months here from 1 to 12, b/c 13 exclusive

        data = accessData(line, j)

        filename = "{}-0{}-2017.csv".format(vals[0], j)

        print(str(filename))
        row_count = len(data)

        for i in range(2, row_count):
            if(data[i] != '<br>\n' and data[i] != '\n'):
                writeFile = open(filename, 'w')
                writeFile.write(data[i])
                openfile = open(Desktop, writeFile , 'r')
                file.close()
```

Comment: Can you just include the path to your desktop as part of `filename`?

Comment: `os.chdir` should be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the script from your desktop. It looks like you haven't specified a directory. So maybe running from your desktop should output your results to your current working directory.

Alternatively, you could try use the [in-built os library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).

```
import os
os.getcwd()    # to get the current working directory
os.chdir(pathname)    # change your working directory to the path specified.
```

This would change your working directory to the place you want to save your files.

Also, in regards to the last four lines of your code. `file` is not open, so you cannot close this. Also, I do not believe you need the `openfile` statement.

```
writeFile = open(filename, 'w')
writeFile.write(data[i])
openfile = open(Desktop, writeFile , 'r')
file.close()
```

Try this instead.

```
with open(filename, 'w') as writeFile:
    for i in range(2, row_count):
        if(data[i] != '<br>\n' and data[i] != '\n'):
            writeFile.write(data[i])
```

Using this approach you shouldn't need to close the file. 'w' is to write as if a new file, change this to 'a' if you need to append to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to provide `writeFile.write()` with the *path* to your destination file, rather than just the filename (which will otherwise be saved into your current working directory.)

Try something like:

```
f = open('stations.csv', 'r')
target_dir = "/path/to/your/Desktop/folder/"
for line in f.readlines():

        ...
        # We can open the file outside your inner "row" loop
        # using the combination of the path to your Desktop
        # and your filename
        with open(target_dir+filename, 'w') as writeFile:
            for i in range(2, row_count):
                 if(data[i] != '<br>\n' and data[i] != '\n'):
                    writeFile.write(data[i])
        # The "writeFile" object will close automatically outside the
        # "with ... " block
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you could approach this two different ways:

1) Run the script directly from the directory to which you would like to save the files. Then you would just need to specify the full path to the .csv file you are reading.

2) You could provide the full path to where you would like to save the files when you write them, however this seems more intensive and unnecessary.

On another note, when opening files for the purpose of reading/writing them, use `with` to simply open the file for as long as you need it, then when you exit the `with` statement, the file will automatically be closed.

Here is an example of Option 1 with some clean-up:

```
import urllib

def accessData(Id, Month):

    url = "https://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=" + str(Id) + "&year=2017&month=" + str(Month) + "&graphspan=month&format=1"
    infile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    readLineByLine = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()

    return readLineByLine

with open('Path to File' + 'stations.csv', 'r') as f:

    for line in f.readlines():

        vals = line.split(',')

        for j in range(1,13):

            data = accessData(line, j)

            filename = "{}-0{}-2017.csv".format(vals[0], j)

            with open(filename, 'w') as myfile:

                for i in range(2, len(data)):
                    if data[i]!='<br>\n' and data[i]!='\n':
                        myfile.write(data[i])

            print(filename + ' - Completed')
```